# Rewrite URL with "-"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi everyone I have the following rewrite rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(\w+)/?$ /blogitem.php?bseo=$1
```

It works fine for most of URL but when I try to use "-" is cannot find the URL, the webserver error is thrown.

I have tested, if I go aroung the rewrite rule it works like

https://ikeen.com/blogitem.php?bseo=nokia-3310

But as soon as I try to access it with rewrite like

https://ikeen.com/blog/nokia-3310

It says 404, any ideas where to look at?

The problem is that I'm trying to transliterate URLs from Russian, using "-" as an alternative to russian soft and hard signs.

Comment: If you don’t know what `\w` actually covers, then https://regex101.com/ can explain it for you.

Comment: I kind of know, but without being an expert I can see that _ works and - not. Any ideas how to actually fix it? Regex is so complex

Comment: Put the `\w` into a character class, and add `-` to that class …

Comment: I'm sorry but it sounds hard to understand. Can you show me the example of a rewrite string based on what I provided. I don't think I understand how to use classes in regex in .htaccess which is populated manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` matches any letter, digit or underscore, but `-` is not included. So you have to add it:

```
RewriteRule ^blog\/([\w-]+)\/?$ /blogitem.php?bseo=$1
```

Keep in mind, that for example `-nokia` or even `-` would also match, see https://regex101.com/r/g5Tgba/1

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer to the question. Without sounding too complex :)